# Exception in delivering result of invoking : TypeError: is not a function in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

When I added in onSuccessCreateClass into meteor.call callback and this error come up. dont know what is wrong here?

> Exception in delivering result of invoking 'createClass': TypeError:
>   this.onSuccessCreateClass is not a function
>       at http://localhost:3000/app/client/components/MyClasses.jsx?044c7b228d4b33fcea4b9f3c05da6d82e5e6c8b7:37:11
>       at null._callback (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?9730f4ff059088b3f7f14c0672d155218a1802d4:999:22)
>       at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3500:12)
>       at *.extend.dataVisible (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3529:10)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:4365:7
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?46eaedbdeb6e71c82af1b16f51c7da4127d6f285:149:11)
>       at _.extend._runAfterUpdateCallbacks (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:4364:7)
>       at _.extend._livedata_data (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:4354:10)
>       at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?250b63e6c919c5383a0511ee4efbf42bb70a650f:3361:12)

```
onSuccessCreateClass() {
    console.log("Successfully created New Class")
    $("#createClassModal").modal('hide')
    $('#createClassModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('form').trigger('reset')
    })
},

onPressSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const className = e.target.cname.value
    console.log(this.props.courseId)
    console.log(className)
    if (Meteor.user().classes.length !== 0)
    {
        console.log("Got Class")
        Meteor.call("createClass", this.props.courseId, className, function(error) {
            if (error)
            {
                console.log(error.reason)
            }
            else
            {
                this.onSuccessCreateClass()
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("No Class")
        Meteor.call("createNewClass", this.props.courseId, className, function(error) {
            if (error)
            {
                console.log(error.reason)
            }
            else
            {
                this.onSuccessCreateClass()
            }
        })
    }
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `this` for callback in `Meteor.call`, because now `this` refers to the global scope or `undefined` if you are using [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). In JavaScript, there is method [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which allows set `this` for method

```
Meteor.call("createClass", this.props.courseId, className, function(error) {
   if (error) {
     console.log(error.reason)
   } else {
     this.onSuccessCreateClass()
   }
}.bind(this))
```

--

```
Meteor.call("createNewClass", this.props.courseId, className, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.reason)
  } else {
    this.onSuccessCreateClass()
  }
}.bind(this))
```